# Cannot deploy docker image in private github registry to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, github-actions

I'm trying to set up an Azure App Service using custom docker images. The images are built in one of my private repo on github and pushed to the github registry. In another repository, I'm setting up the deploy workflow through Github Actions and I followed the steps in this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-container-github-action?tabs=publish-profile#deploy-to-an-app-service-container).

The current workflow is defined as follows:

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - uses: azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: ghcr.io/
        username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

    - uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'my-app-name'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
        images: 'ghcr.io/${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME}}/my-repo-name:my-tag'
```

Once pushed, the action runs successfully. But when I go to the app URL, it is not displayed due to errors.

The following are the Azure App Service logs related to Docker Engine:
[image]
where red is my github username, green is my private repo (which is also the image name), blue is the image tag and yellow the Azure App Service name.

What is going wrong?

The only hint I have is that the `azure/docker-login` action only logs to the private github registry within the action workflow, but when the App Service is started it requires to log in again to the private registry to pull the image. But I could not find any instruction on how to provide again the credentials to log in.

**EDIT 1:**

I set `secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME` to my github username and `secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD` to my github account password, since I think these are the right credentials to log in into my private github registry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to publish the docker image using git repository (code-base). Code build and push build artifacts part in another action and this action read those build artifacts and builds a docker image.

The best practice is to push the image to the Azure container registry and use that image in Azure web app

```
jobs:
      docker:
        name: "Docker"
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Download artifact
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
            with:
              name: ${{ inputs.download_artifact_name }}
          - name: Log into registry
            uses: docker/login-action@v1
            with:
              registry: ${{ secrets.ACR_ENDPOINT }}
              username: ${{ secrets.ACR_USERNAME }}
              password: ${{ secrets.ACR_PASSWORD }}
          - name: Build & Push
            uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
            with:
              push: true
              file: ${{ inputs.docker_filepath }}
              tags: ${{ secrets.ACR_ENDPOINT }}/${{ inputs.docker_imagename }}:${{github.run_number}}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this! Why best practice is to use Azure Container Registry? Azure app service allows one the choose any private registry, so that I expect that also github registry is fine (which also is under Microsoft)

Comment: yes. any private registry is working. you need only the container registry name, username & password

Comment: Actually pushing the image to Azure container registry and connecting Azure app service to it is working. But still I would like to have a solution with integration with Github

Comment: what did you mean by integration with GitHub? your GitHub action builds a docker image and pushes it to the private container registry. right?
Then you will deploy that docker image to azure web using same action or different action

Comment: yeah, exactly, my action pushes the built image to github registry. But cannot make to work neither another action to deploy on app service, nor the direct connection of app service to the private github registry. In both cases, app service docker logs showed an "unauthorized" error (but provided credentials were ok)

Comment: did you try to pull an image from the GitHub registry using a username & password? may be that will help to understand something of error

Comment: yes, I tried and I correctly pull the image locally on my machine by providing username and password to docker login

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the push part.

Here you have an example how to use it with ghcr and some style.

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Login to docker registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Docker meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        id: meta
        with:
          images: "ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}"
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr

      - name: Build and push docker
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      - uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: "my-app-name"
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          images: "${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}"
```

- `docker/login-action` - you can use built in variables for auth
- `docker/metadata-action` - generates tags for you. See docs for more config options.
- `docker/build-push-action` - exactly what the name says. This is what you were missing the most.
- `images: "${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}"` - use autogenerated tag :)

To further improve this job could be split into two `build` and `deploy`

Comment: Thank you! But I'm not missing the push part, this is just done in another repository (call it repo A), where the source code of my app resides. The example that I provided is from repo B which I want to use as pure deployment repo. Action in repo B works correctly (success, logs say that image is correctly deployed into azure app service), but actually app service cannot pull the image (docker engine logs provided in question).

Comment: I see. If both repos are in the same org/account you could use `github.token` but first you need to assign a permission to the package so that repo B can access it.